# Execute remote command

Tags: ssh, remote-access, remote, remote-control

I use autossh to keep a connection open to a remote mysql server.

```
autossh -p 22 -M 0 -L 33061:localhost:3306 root@10.0.0.101 -f -C -N
```

Basically, whenever I type:

```
mysql -h localhost -P33061
```

I access mysql server on the remote mysql server.

Now, I would like to have another connection open to another server and would like to execute certain commands on the remote server. How do I do this?

The only workaround I found is to always

```
connect to remote server
execute command on remote server
disconnect from remote server.
```

I do this via a similar command:

```
ssh root@10.0.0.2 -p 22 "ls"
```

The problem with this approach is that it always connect first, execute the command then disconnect. And this takes time. I want to keep the connection always open and execute from shell commands from the remote machine.

So, I should autossh to remote, autossh will keep the connection open and I would need the correct way to execute the `ls` command on remote server (returning the result locally).

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a feature called SSH multiplexing, i.e. the re-use of a single existing TCP connection for multiple SSH sessions. Here's an example of how you can enable this in your `ssh_config`:

```
Host myserver
    User root
    HostName 10.0.0.2
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p
    ControlPersist 10m
```

`ControlMaster` activates the multiplexing for this host.

`ControlPath` sets the path of the "control socket" (can be anywhere you want)

`ControlPersist` will keep the connection open in the background for the specified period of time (after the last connection has been exited).

When you establish an initial (master) connection to `myserver`, e.g. via `ssh myserver "ls"`, a control socket will be created in the location specified by the `ControlPath` setting above. In this case it would be `~/.ssh/root@10.0.0.2:22`, where *root* corresponds to the `%r` token (remote username), *10.0.0.2* to the `%h` token (target host name), and *22* to the `%p` token (destination port) in that entry. This socket file will exist for as long as the master connection remains open in the background.

Now each time you make subsequent attempts to connect to `myserver`, for example with another `ssh myserver "ls"`, the master connection will be reused.

Refer to `ssh_config(5)` for more details on how you can adjust these settings to achieve what you want (for example if you want to keep the connection open indefinitely, etc).